# Excel Find VBA is not working

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

Here is the code I tried. But it is stuck in finding the cell (`Set RangeObj = Cells.find`).

Please check the following code:

```
Sub CopyFromFile()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String
Filepath = "C:\Users\Nazmul Hossain Akash\Desktop\Play Excel\Final\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
    Range("B2:D18").Copy
    Set RangeObj = Cells(1, "A")
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Set RangeObj = Cells.Find(What:=RangeObj, After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If RangeObj Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Not Found" Else RangeObj.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=2, columnOffset:=0).Activate

    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

    MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: **1.** Always use `Option Explicit`when coding! You never `Dim` your `RangeObj` **2.** Always be **explicit** when referencing ranges. When you state `Set RangeObj = Cells(1, "A")`, VBA does not know which workbook and worksheet you talk about, so it does its best guess. You should do something like: `Set RangeObj = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "A")`. **3.** I am sure you get error, because after you `set` the `RangeObj`, you close that workbook... Be more explicit in referencing the workbook that you need.

Comment: I cant not define a sheet name here, because every file has a name with their file name. so i use now this http://prntscr.com/7gtdn3

Answer (score 2):

I think I see the problem. You still do not `Dim` your `RangeObj` (and I see no `Option Explicit` at the top! - please add it). That will make you `Dim` every variable, therefore you will have to decide what data type will the variable be, including `RangeObj`. And `RangeObj` here is a problem. Since you do `Set RangeObj = Cells.Find()`, it's OK to have this as a range object. However, before that you do `Set RangeObj = ActiveWorkbook.Cells(1, "A")` - you `Set` it. And this is a mistake, because this way you get an object, and after that you want to use it in `.Find()`. You should pass anything to `.Find()`, but not an object. Let's try fixing the problem:

1. Insert this line at the very top:

   ```
   Option Explicit
   ```
2. Dim your RangeObj:

   ```
   Dim RangeObj as Range
   ```
3. Introduce another variable for storing text to `.find()`:

   ```
   Dim RangeStr as String
   ```
4. Replace `Set RangeObj = ActiveWorkbook.Cells(1, "A")` with `RangeStr = ActiveWorkbook.Cells(1, "A").Value`
5. Replace `Cells.Find(What:=RangeObj,` with `Cells.Find(What:=RangeStr,`

Let's see what it brings.